# Spring-xd Redis sink with Collection type MAP

Tags: redis, spring-xd

Im trying to implement Redis sink with specific to collection type = MAP

```
stream create tTEST_GF_SINK --definition "trigger --initialDelay=0 --fixedDelay=1 --timeUnit=MINUTES --payload= 'new Date().toString()' --outputType=application/json | 
  transform --expression='new java.util.Date().toString()'| 
  redis --collectionType=MAP --key=1" --deploy
```

For all other collection types like LIST , SET ,ZSET  stream is able to write into these redis sinks but when I am using MAP as a collection type then it throwing following error on redis_mapkey.

> 2017-06-30T16:47:59-0400 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-3 handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Failed to store Message data in Redis collection; **nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 8): Property or field 'redis_mapKey' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders' - maybe not public?**
>       at org.springframework.integration.redis.outbound.RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.java:278)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:161)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:251)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 8): Property or field 'redis_mapKey' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders' - maybe not public?
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:374)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267)
>       at org.springframework.integration.redis.outbound.RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.determineMapKey(RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.java:415)
>       at org.springframework.integration.redis.outbound.RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.writeToMap(RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.java:379)
>       at org.springframework.integration.redis.outbound.RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler.java:271)
>       ... 99 more

Can any one help me up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a MAP collection, there are two keys involved; the key the map is stored under and the key the element is stored in the map with.

The XD module doesn't expose the mapKey as a property. You can either add a header-enricher upstream to set the `redis_mapKey` header, or you can edit the module's configuration to add the `map-key-expression`.

For example, editing `xd/modules/sink/redis/config/redis.xml` like so...

```
<beans:beans profile="use-store-expression">
    <redis:store-outbound-channel-adapter
        map-key-expression="payload.substring(17)"
        key-expression="${keyExpression}" collection-type="${collectionType}"
        channel="input" connection-factory="redisConnectionFactory" />
</beans:beans>
```

with...

```
xd:>stream create foo --definition "time | redis --collectionType=MAP --key='foo'" --deploy
```

results in...

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall "foo"
 1) "52"
 2) "2017-07-01 08:43:52"
 3) "53"
 4) "2017-07-01 08:43:53"
 5) "54"
 6) "2017-07-01 08:43:54"
 7) "55"
 8) "2017-07-01 08:43:55"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gary . I tried your suggestion for header-enricher to add redis_mapkey. Its working fine.

> stream create tTEST_GF_SINK --definition "trigger --initialDelay=0 --fixedDelay=1 --timeUnit=MINUTES --payload= 'new Date().toString()' --outputType=application/json |**header-enricher --headers={\"redis_mapKey\":\"payload.substring(17)\"}**| transform --expression='new java.util.Date().toString()'|  redis --collectionType=MAP --key=1" --deploy

127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall 1

1) "ng()"

2) "Sat Jul 01 23:29:16 EDT 2017"